# python - import data from url to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, url, dataframe, import

Can you please help me to code the import the data coming from this url into a pandas dataframe? Is a time serie of a mutual fund and I need to make some statistical analysis and plot.

http://tools.morningstar.it/api/rest.svc/timeseries_price/jbyiq3rhyf?currencyId=EURtype=Morningstar&frequency=daily&startDate=2008-04-01&priceType=&outputType=COMPACTJSON&id=F00000YU62]2]0]FOITA$$ALL&applyTrackRecordExtension=true

Any hint is appreciated to understand how it works

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer to get result:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
URL ='http://tools.morningstar.it/api/rest.svc/timeseries_price/jbyiq3rhyf?currencyId=EURtype=Morningstar&frequency=daily&startDate=2008-04-01&priceType=&outputType=COMPACTJSON&id=F00000YU62]2]0]FOITA$$ALL&applyTrackRecordExtension=true'
r = requests.get(URL)
# a= eval(r.content) Never user eval for online texts
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```

## Answer to understand whats going on

In my answer, I use a little trick that is not recommended all the times. 
First, 
*I used request to get data from URL and then evaluate it using python `eval` function, as you can see its a nested list.* **But its a better idea to use `r.json()`**

`pandas.DataFrame` is a method that converts data to data frame using different method for example you can use nested list or json like data(like dictionaries) to create a Dataframe.

But In most case results from web can become a pandas Dataframe using  `pd.read_csv` it parse data using `sep` and `lineterminator`.

Comment: Then somebody puts some evil code in that url, you execute it with `eval` and you are screwed. Just because you weren't careful enough to use `a = r.json()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use pd.read_json(URL)

```
import pandas as pd
URL = "http://your.url.com/api"
pd.read_json(URL)
```